# Playing Video in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning-community

I am trying to show video in a community page.
The below aura component works in salesforce internally but not in community. The samplevideomp4 file is placed in asset library.

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" >
  test
    <video width="60%" height="50%" controls="controls">
        <source src="/file-asset-public/samplevideomp4" type="video/mp4" />  
   </video> 
</aura:component>
```

The below LWC works in community but not in salesforce.

```
//html
<template>
    <video width="60%" height="50%" controls="controls">
       <source src={sampleVideo} type="video/mp4" />               
   </video>  
 </template>

//js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import sampleVideoAsset from '@salesforce/contentAssetUrl/samplevideomp4';

export default class VideoPlayer extends LightningElement {

    sampleVideo = sampleVideoAsset;

}

//meta
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>48.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
        <target>lightning__Tab</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>

    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember that a community has a different URL which is why the Aura component doesn't work. Please edit the question to explain what is wrong with the LWC; what does "it doesn't work in Salesforce" actually mean?

Comment: Phil, how can I make the aura component show video in community? what url should I give for it to work in community, I have tried with relative url and it does not work

Comment: Not sure exactly, since I never used file assets (attachments and static resources only for me) but your community usually has an extra URL path prefix to add to make host relative URLs work.

Comment: @PhilW please share if you have a solution for this issue.

Comment: @Bforce I did not experiment to find the solution, sorry.

Comment: @sfdcdev Kindly share if you have a solution for this issue.